# wierd colon (:) appearing when hovering over text

Tags: jquery, html, css

**CSS**

```
.hvtext {
    font-family:mainText;
    font-size:14px;
    color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
    font-weight:bold;
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.hvtext:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
    color:rgba(51,51,51,1);
}
```

**JavaScript**:

```
$(function () {
    $('#twitter').hover(function () {
        $(this).append('<p class="hvtext">twitter</p>');
        $('.hvtext').css({left:'1.7em', bottom: '0.1em'});
    }, function () {
        $('.hvtext').hide();
    });

    $('#about').hover(function () {
        $(this).append('<p class="hvtext">about</p>');
        $('.hvtext').css({left:'1.7em', bottom:'0.1em'});
    }, function () {
        $('.hvtext').hide();
    });

    $('#contact').hover(function () {
        $(this).append('<p class="hvtext">contact</p>')
        $('.hvtext').css({left:'1.2em', bottom:'0.1em'});
    }, function () {
        $('.hvtext').hide();
    });

    $('#experience').hover(function () {
        $(this).append('<p class="hvtext">exp</p>');
        $('.hvtext').css({left:'2.3em', bottom:'0.1em'});
    }, function() {
        $('.hvtext').hide();
    });

    $('#prices').hover(function () {
        $(this).append('<p class="hvtext">price</p>');
        $('.hvtext').css({left:'2em',bottom:'0.5'});
    }, function () {
        $('.hvtext').hide();
    });
});
```

The text is added dynamically when hovering over one of divs, (purple div in picture). When  you hover over the text it changes color and I've added a css3 transition.

However a weird white colon (`:`) is showing up at the end of the first, second and 3rd blocks/texts when you hover over them.

Screenshot :

[image]

Comment: I don't think that's a colon. It's the rightmost tips of the `t`.

Comment: could be the t, and it does occur with 'contact' but it also appears slightly here:   http://i.imgur.com/dT2rFL9.png

Comment: Can you post your HTML part?

Comment: html for this section:  http://jsfiddle.net/7nNLy/
like i said they're just normal <div>'s and the text and hover are added dynamically

Comment: hvtext class is added dynamically by the js with .append:   $(this).append('<p class="hvtext">about</p>');

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a `:` (colon)..

I'm going to take a guess and say that it's a browser error rendering the font, it looks like you're using a **custom font**, and I always get issues with chrome chopping off the bottom of my fonts but if I scroll up and down a bit it disappears, If it is what I think it is I don't think you'll find a way around this.

> **Evidence that this could be the issue**
>
> **1.** If you take a close look at the screenshot, you can see that the dots line up perfectly with the t's bottom and cross to the upper middle.
>
> **2.** The 2 dots also line up perfectly vertically and horizontally, there is no space between the **t** and the dots.

**How do I confirm this is actually the issue?**

Change the word to **HELLO**, then see what happens

Try this test code and see what happens

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    $('a').css('color', '#444');
}, 700);
```

Just see if re-rendering the element will fix it.

Comment: Yea you're probably right about the custom font, ill try with a normal font. "I don't think this is a : (colon).."  I just meant that's what it looked like

Comment: @joe try changing the text.

Comment: ok changed the word to 'Hello' and the dots are gone: http://i.imgur.com/iWfXTIX.png also worth noting that the dots don't show up at all on the words 'exp' and 'price' : http://i.imgur.com/Sugbri7.png

Comment: I changed the font to a 'Arial' and while the dots were much less visible you can still see a very small white dot at the bottom of the t:  http://i.imgur.com/O5Uwzlk.png

Comment: Try the code i've just added to answer, see what happens... Make sure `a` points to the element with the issue

Comment: still not working :/ You're probably right about the custom font, also the transition might be messing up the rendering.